# Using ddply()/plotting means and error bars in r

Tags: r

I have a homework question to plot the mean `Length` by `Sex` and `Region`, as well as plot error bars `+/-1 SE of the mean`. I have tried using the following -

```
Lab_Cultures2 <- ddply(Lab_Cultures,.(Sex,Region)),summarise,M=mean(`Length (mm)`),
                       SE=sd(`Length (mm)`)/sqrt(length(`Length (mm)`)),SD=sd(`Length (mm)`)
```

but keep getting an

> unexpected ',' error

I cannot move on to try and plot without first getting through this (I assume?). Please let me know if you need my data set and thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Yes, share output of `dput(head(your_df))`. Also, just check that you closed all brackets correctly. For a start `ddply` function is closed after second closing parenthesis in `.(Sex,Region))` causing the shown error.

Comment: @Shree I'm not sure what you mean by dput(head(your_df)) but I was able to fix the error and got a table with Sex,Region,Mean,SE,SD thank you so much! Any advice on how to go about plotting the means of length(mm) with +/-1 SE error bars?